How to differentiate number and bigint interpolated in strings
Typescript seem to make no difference between number and bigint when interpolated in strings.
type Test1<T extends string> = T extends `${infer R extends bigint}` ? R : never
type Test2<T extends string> = T extends `${infer R extends number}` ? R : never

type _result1 = Test1<'1'>
//   ^? type _result1 = 1n // expected never
type _result2 = Test1<`${1n}`>
//   ^? type _result2 = 1n // valid
type _result3 = Test2<'1'>
//   ^? type _result3 = 1  // valid
type _result4 = Test2<`${1n}`>
//   ^? type _result4 = 1  // expected never

playgroung
His they're a way to differientiate them ?

I understand from your comment that I can't solve my issue - I was hoping to be able to differientiate them after serialisation

and i did not know that 1n was serialized in typescript to 1
Is they re a doc that sepcifies this ?

thank you @jcalz
How can I close the question ?

I'll write up an answer if you don't mind.

No, what you are trying to do is impossible.
TypeScript Template literal types as implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#40336 are intended to be the type equivalent of JavaScript template literal strings.  That is, roughly, if you have a value x of type X, then the template literal string `${x}` is of type `${X}`.  (There's more to it than that, since X needs to be one of the types TypeScript considers serializable, and template literal strings are sometimes widened to just string in TypeScript, and conditional type inference has some slightly inconsistent behavior with template literal types, but none of these caveats are important for your question).

That means the type `${1n}` is the type of the value `${1n}`. The latter is the string "1":
console.log(`${1n}`); // "1"

So the type is also the string literal type "1":
type Z = `${1n}`;
//   ^? type Z = "1"

Similarly, the type `${1}` is also the string literal type "1":
console.log(`${1}`); // "1"
type Z = `${1}`;
//   ^? type Z = "1"

And for good measure, the type `${"1"}` is also the string literal type "1":
console.log(`${"1"}`); // "1"
type Z = `${"1"}`;
//   ^? type Z = "1"

All three of those serialize to the same thing. The types `${1n}` and `${1}` and `${"1"}` and "1" are all just different ways of writing the same type. Thus one cannot possibly distinguish between them.  String literal types don't carry around references to how they were originally written; that information is gone, and you can't recover it by trying to infer it.
If you ask TypeScript to infer a bigint from a string literal type, it will do so, even if that string literal type was originally written as a serialized number or a string.  In the code you've written, Test1 just parses string literal types as bigints , and Test2 parses string literal types as numbers. Those are useful behaviors in their own right, but they do not and cannot retrieve the discarded information about where their string literal inputs might have come from.
Playground link to code
